# Additional parameters are not storing in Firebase database after task is successful?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

This is my Register.java page.Here I am not able to store name and phone number in the database.When I try to store there is no response.

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText mEmail;
private EditText mPassword;
private EditText mPhone;
private EditText mName;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
DatabaseReference mData;


public void register(View v)
{
 startRegister();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
    mName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    mData=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    progressBar = new ProgressBar(Register.this,null,android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);



    RelativeLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    layout.addView(progressBar,params);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


}

private void startRegister(){
    String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
    String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
    final String phone = mPhone.getText().toString();
    final String name = mName.getText().toString();

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(password)&&!TextUtils.isEmpty(phone)&&!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)&&!TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){



        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(Register.this,new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {



            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if(task.isSuccessful()){

                    String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();



                    DatabaseReference current_user_db = mData.child(user_id);

                    current_user_db.child("name").setValue(name);
                    current_user_db.child("phone").setValue(phone);
                    //mName.getText().toString() mPhone.getText().toString()

                     //  getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
                    //  progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                  //  Intent main =new Intent(Register.this,MainActivity.class);
                   // startActivity(main);

                }
            }

        });

    }

}
```

}

My gradle code is
   `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
 android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ashwanths.helpwithfood"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}




apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
```

Or can you specify any other way in which I can add all the data simultaneously data's include(name , emailId , password , phone Number)

Comment: are you able to go to the next activity?

Comment: Ya it is automatically going to next Activity after the authentication is finished when DatabaseReference  is not added.But if I add the database reference it is not moving to next Activity nor it is storing the email or password.

Comment: it is staying in the same activity, are you getting any errors?

Comment: It is staying in the same activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, since this is on signup and not login:

```
FirebaseUser users;
if(task.isSuccessful()){

   users= task.getResult().getUser();
   DatabaseReference ref = mData.child(users.getUid());
   ref.child("name").setValue(name);
   ref.child("phone").setValue(phone);
```

Then you will have in the database:

```
Users
 useruid
    name: name_here
    phone: phone_here
```

Comment: No it is not storing in database but it is moving to the next Activity.

Comment: change your firebase database rules to read:true and write:true @ashwanths